# jQuery -- Changing the value in the SELECT does not trigger the AJAX event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm desperately trying to figure out how to get it so that the AJAX event is triggered correctly on [this page](http://store.tintworld.com/interior-exterior-accessories-lighting/wiper-blades/windshield-wiper-blade.html). At the moment I've set it so that on page load, the year in the top widget should be getting set to 2003 via the following code...

```
if ((jQuery("div.amfinder-horizontal td:nth-child(1) select").val() == "0")) {

    jQuery("div.amfinder-horizontal td:nth-child(1) select option").each(function() { this.selected = (this.text == "2003"); });

    jQuery("div.amfinder-horizontal td:nth-child(1) select option").change();

    console.log('Set the year!');
}
```

It seems to work visually but you can't proceed forward with selecting a 'Make' (the next in the chain) unless you go back to Year and select a value with your mouse. The widget at the top was built in Prototype but I thought I could fire the events off the same way with jQuery. Am I mistaken in thinking so, or is this something ridiculously easy otherwise?

Thanks!

Comment: An option doesn't have a change event, a select has

Comment: Thank you -- I updated the code as per the answer below, but it still doesn't trigger the AJAX event. I'm looking into it now but any additional advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ((jQuery("div.amfinder-horizontal td:nth-child(1) select").val() == "0")) {

    jQuery("div.amfinder-horizontal td:nth-child(1) select option").each(function() { this.selected = (this.text == "2003"); });

    //bind to select, not change
    jQuery("div.amfinder-horizontal td:nth-child(1) select").change(); 

    console.log('Set the year!');
}
```

Comment: Thank you -- I updated the code as per the answer below, but it still doesn't trigger the AJAX event. I'm looking into it now but any additional advice is much appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to provide more code. I don't see anything related to AJAX in your snippet.